# reversDigits is printing out base case input is not base case (java)

Tags: java, recursion, methods, case, radix

The input for this method is "9876548"

```
It returns 
8
4 
5
6
7
8
9
9876548
```

I don't want the "9876548" at the end.

(Stack over flow format wont all

Implement a recursive method printDigits that takes an integer num as a parameter and prints its digits in reverse order, one digit per line.

```
public class PrintDigits{

  public static void main (String [] args)
     {System.out.print(reversDigits(9876548));}

        public static int reversDigits(int number) {
           int result;

           if (number < 10) {
           System.out.println(number);
           result = number;
           }

           else{
           System.out.println(number % 10);
           reversDigits(number/10);
           result = number;
           }
           return result;
        }


        }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this
     System.out.print(reversDigits(9876548));

to 
     reversDigits(9876548);

Comment: Thank you! It worked, I can't believe something so simple was the answer!

Comment: @Jovan that's programming... this happens to all of us. try, try try, test, test test and never lose focus :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this way

```
public static void main (String [] args)
     {
      reversDigits(9876548);
      }

        public static int reversDigits(int number) {
           int result;

           if (number < 10) {
           System.out.println(number);
           result = number;
           }

           else{
           System.out.println(number % 10);
           reversDigits(number/10);
           result = number;
           }
           return result;
        }
```